# How to view Parent when in Child controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ShoesController#choose_store_shoes

Couldn't find Store without an ID
```

Keep in mind that `shoes` belong to a `Store`. This all takes place in the shoes controller, beginning in the `see_shoes` action and then when a user clicks on a `Store` it uses the `choose_store_shoes` action. This should show the store and the shoes. I just need help actually getting to the page.

```
ShoesController

  def see_stores
   @stores = Store.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  end

  def choose_store_shoes
   @store = Store.find(params[:id])
  end
```

My Routes:

```
resources :shoes do
  collection do
     get 'see_stores'
     get 'choose_store_shoes'
  end
end
```

Then my view where you click on a store and it should show it:

```
<% for store in @stores %>
   <%= link_to choose_store_shoes_shoes_path(store.id) do %>
      <%= store.name %>
      <%= store.location %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I think I'm linking or routing it incorrectly. What would be the right way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're parsing :id, when there is no :id in the url scheme. You need to fix your routes.

In your routes.rb, change `collection do` to `member do` so that the url scheme accepts an :id.

After you have made this change to your route, you can then specify which store you want with the proper id: `127.0.0.1:3000/shoes/:id/choose_store_shoes`

Comment: Thank you. Also had to change my `link_to` a little to this: `<%= link_to choose_store_shoes_shoe_path(store) do %>`